# "File <unspecified filename> was not found" in ESXi after modifying VM settings

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I have an ESXi 4.1 host with a few servers - two of which are Windows Server 2008 R2 VMs. Server #2 was a copy of Server #1. When I made the clone I'm pretty sure I copied the .vmdk and .vmx files to a new folder via vSphere Client datastore, and then hit 'Add to Inventory' on the .vmx. Each VM starts up and runs Windows, and identifies itself correctly.

However, when I make a change to the settings on Server #2 via vSphere, I receive this error after saving: "File <unspecified filename> was not found". In this case, I was simply changing the network label on the nic. I get the feeling there is some bad juju left-over from the clone, but I'd prefer not to rebuild this server from scratch.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"When I made the clone I'm pretty sure I copied the .vmdk and .vmx files to a new folder via vSphere Client datastore, and then hit 'Add to Inventory'"

This isn't cloning but just copying, am I wrong?  It sounds like you went to the datastore, right clicked on the VM files and selected copy?  From you description you have 2 servers with the same SID/CMID.  Also if you only copied those 2 files I think you are missing a few there.  http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_learning_files_in_a_vm.html

I would have right clicked on the server in vCenter and done actual cloning, not copying, from there.  You can customize the clone after that to create a unique SID/CMID (sysprep).

Comment: This particular VM host uses the newer 4.1 ESXi hypervisor, while the other hosts in our environment use an older version. We are trying to save money where possible, and using the ESXi hypervisor for free seemed like a viable option. However, since I can't manage it with our current vCenter (old!), and simply copying the files won't really work, then I might need to bite the bullet and request a license upgrade.